# XML ellipsis / other syntax - what's it called?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

I ran into the following piece of code that puzzled me at first glance. I wasn't able to find resources on this, due to its nature it's kind of hard to search for. I'm of course puzzled by the `...<price>` portion of this. What's the syntax / concept called, what is it doing, or where can I read more about the concept? I'm sure it's not complicated, I just don't know what to look for and wasn't even sure how to phrase the question! Is `...` separate from `<price>`? What types do those return? And any other general info. Thanks!

```
Price = xml_GetElementValue(xml...<price>.FirstOrDefault)
```

Comment: What does this `xml_GetElementValue` method signature look like?

Comment: @GrantThomas haha. And EkoostikMartin, xml_GetElementValue(XElement). The 'xml' variable itself is an XElement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It selects a sub-child element `<price>` under the `xml` XElement.
It's a LINQ to XML notation in VB.

Provides access to the descendants of the following: an XElement object, an XDocument object, a collection of XElement objects, or a collection of XDocument objects.

`object...<descendant>`

See: XML Descendant Axis Property (Visual Basic)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384876.aspx

Comment: Yes, of course there is a way in .NET via explicit call to Descendants("<element>") - that's what C# folks would do.
Also note there is an `object.<child>` notation as well for direct children.